# Uefi event logs

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, logs

I am unable to get the event logs in uefi mode tried in different ways like from BIOS settings of Intel NUC board and tried using the UEFI application but failed to collect UEFI event logs also tried on different platforms like lenovo thinkboot advanced setting options also but no option available for collecting event logs
expecting to know how to get uefi event logs to catch in a file